# Via logwatch, I get messages that root is opening sessions "-> nobody". Is this a security concern, or normal operation?

Tags: security, ssh, logging, logwatch

Here are some lines from logwatch:

```
pam_unix

sshd:   Authentication Failures:
     root (211.167.103.115): 5 Time(s)
     unknown (219.239.110.139): 1 Time(s)   Invalid Users:
     Unknown Account: 1 Time(s) 

su:   Sessions Opened:
     root -> nobody: 3 Time(s)
```

Now, taken alone I would assume that the `su` entries are just some timed escalation of privileges (or descalation, as the case may be), but in conjunction with the standard attempts at root password cracking, they're more unsettling.  Should I be concerned about security holes due to either of these sets of notice/logwatch entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be concerned about "authentication failures" for root - there are myriads of malware and scriptkiddies tools trying root passwords on every host they can reach. As long as you do not allow direct root logins and / or have a sufficiently complex non-dictionary root password, this is nothing to worry about.

The root -> nobody sessions are indeed dropped priveleges - something that starts as root and changes the security context to the unpriveleged "nobody" user - which is good security practice.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to make sure.  Just a little bit of a follow up question, even in the cases where root login is disabled (my intent and the way that I have configured ssh, as well as denyhost), do those authentication failure messages still occur?

Comment: OpenSSHd just logs an "invalid user root" login attempt, not an "authentication failure" as it does with an incorrect password

Comment: `root -> nobody` comes from crons.

Comment: Hmmm, okay, so that may be indicative of the configuration still allowing attempts on the root account's password, good to know.